# Error when publishing: Unable to add file 'xxxx'. Access is denied

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, publish

I'm getting this error when I try to publish.  Not on *all* files, just on a handful.

> Unable to add file 'webservices\initial_audit_svc.asmx'.  Access is denied.

I checked the properties to make sure they're not "read only", and they're fine.

Can anyone think of any other reason why I might get this error while publishing?

Comment: The file is in the specific folder that administrator/some user permission is required to access.

Comment: try to copy the file to another location. if it works, the problem may come from the folder

Comment: Unfortunately, some files from the same folders get copied and some don't.  That's why I thought it might be properties-based.

Comment: Last chance: creating new project, copy some parts from current projec to new project and publishing it. After successful, copy the other parts to new project and re-publish. Continue to finish.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone ever experiences this, I finally discovered the answer.

The files were marked as "Read-Only" on the *server* I was publishing to, and not my local version.  No idea how that happened.  Also, 2 of them were marked as "Block", so I had to unblock them.  All of this was found on the Properties popup for the file on our Production server.

Answer (score 0):

just run visual studio as "run as administrator" and it worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).